# Neighboring gray-level dependence matrix (NGLDM) in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, matrix, feature-extraction

I would like to calculate a couple of texture features (namely: small/ large number emphasis, number non-uniformity, second moment and entropy). Those can be computed from Neighboring gray-level dependence matrix. I'm struggling with understanding/implementation of this. There is very little info on this method (publicly available).

According to [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/3870):

> This matrix takes the form of a two-dimensional array *Q*, where *Q(i,j)* can be considered as frequency counts of grayness variation of a processed image. It has a similar meaning as histogram of an image. This array is N<sub>g</sub>×N<sub>r</sub> where N<sub>g</sub> is the number of possible gray levels and  N<sub>r</sub> is the number of possible neighbours to a pixel in an image.
>
> If the image function *f(i,j)* is discrete, then it is easy to computer the *Q* matrix (for positive integer *d, a*) by counting the number of times the difference between each element in *f(i,j)* and its neighbours is equal or less than *a* at a certain distance *d*.

Here is the example from the same paper (*d = 1, a = 0*):

Input (image) matrix and output matrix *Q*:

[image: Input (image) matrix]
[image]

I've been looking at this example for hours now and still can't figure out how they got that *Q* matrix. Anyone?

<sub>The method was originally created by C. Sun and W. Wee and was described in a paper called: "[Neighboring gray level dependence matrix for texture classification](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0734189X83900324)" to which I got access, but can't download (after pressing download the page reloads and that's it).</sub>

Comment: No idea what the answer is, but maybe my thoughts will start a discussion or help someone else see it. If d=1, we are talking about immediate (adjacent) neighbours and if a=0, we are looking for a difference of zero, so we are looking for identical immediate neighbours - I think! The 4 in the NGLDM must be the key to understanding - there must be a pixel with 4 immediate identical neighbours, which kind of looks like the 2x2 grid of 2s in the bottom right of the input matrix - but no idea how that explains a thing!

Comment: I figured it out.  I'll write an answer

Comment: I think that you are interested about the [gray-level co-occurrence matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graycomatrix.html). The same matrix is used to compute [Haralick texture features](http://dceanalysis.bigr.nl/Haralick73-Textural%20features%20for%20image%20classification.pdf)

Comment: @Thoth - This is different than the co-occurrence matrix.  This counts the total number of times the neighbours of a pixel equals the centre... given the example

Comment: @MarkSetchell and sowizz - I have written an answer... and as a bonus, I have also written MATLAB code that computes this matrix.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example that you have provided, `d=1` and `a=0`.  When `d=1`, we consider pixels in an 8-pixel neighbourhood.  When `a=0`, this means that we look for pixels that have the same value as the centre of the neighbourhood.

The basic algorithm is the following:

1. Initialize your NGLDM matrix to all zeroes.  The total number of rows corresponds to the total number of possible intensities / values in your image.  The total number of columns corresponds to how many pixels are in your neighbourhood plus 1.  As such for `d=1`, we have an 8-pixel neighbourhood and so 8 + 1 = 9.  Because there are 4 possible intensities `(0,1,2,3)`, we thus have a 4 x 9 matrix.  Let's call this matrix `M`.
2. For each pixel in your matrix, take note of this pixel.  This goes in the `Ng` row.
3. Write out **how many** valid neighbours there are that surround this pixel.
4. Count how many times you see the neighbouring pixels matching that pixel in Step #1.  This is your `Nr` column.
5. Once you figure out the numbers in Step #1 and Step #2, increment this location by 1.

---

Here's a slight gotcha:  **They ignore the border locations**.  As such, you don't do this procedure for the first row, last row, first column or last column.  My guess is that they want to be sure that you have an 8-pixel neighbourhood all the time.  This is also dictated by the distance `d=1`.  You **must** be able to grab every valid pixel given a centre location at `d=1`.  If `d=2`, then you would have to make sure that every pixel in the centre of the neighbourhood has a 25 pixel neighbourhood and so on.

Let's start from the second row, second column location of this matrix.  Let's go through the steps:

1. `Ng = 1` as the location is 1.
2. Valid neighbours - Starting from the top left pixel in this neighbourhood, and scanning left to right and omitting the centre, we have: `1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2`.
3. How many values are equal to `1`?  Three times.  Therefore `Nr = 3`
4. `M(Ng,Nr) += 1`.  Access row `Ng = 1`, and access row `Nr = 3`, and increment this spot by 1.

---

Want to know how I figured out they don't count the borders?  Let's do the bottom left pixel.  That location is `0`, so `Ng = 0`.  If you repeat the algorithm that I just said, you would expect `Ng = 0`, `Nr = 1`, and so you would expect at least one entry in that location in your matrix... but you don't!  If you do similar checks around the border of the image, you'll see that entries that are supposed to be there... aren't.  Take a look at the third row, fifth column.  You would think that `Ng = 1` and `Nr = 1`, but we don't see that in the matrix.

---

One more example.  Why is `M(Ng,Nr) = 4, Ng = 2, Nr = 4`?  Well, take a look at every pixel that has a `2` in it.  The only valid locations where we can capture an 8 pixel neighbourhood successfully are the `row=2, col=4`, `row=3, col=3`, `row=3, col=4`, `row=4, col=3`, and `row=4, col=4`.  By applying the same algorithm that we have seen, you'll see that for each of those locations, `Nr = 4`.  As such, we see this combination of `Ng = 2, Nr = 4` **four** times, and that's why the location is set to 4.  However, in `row=3, col=4`, this actually is `Nr = 5`, as there are **five** 2s in that neighbourhood at that centre.  That's why you see `Ng = 2, Nr = 5, M(Ng,Nr) = 1`.

As an example, let's do one of the locations.  Let's do the `2` smack dab in the middle of the matrix (`row=3, col=3`):

1. `Ng = 2`
2. What are the valid neighbouring pixels?  `1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2` (omit the centre)
3. Count how many pixels equal to 2.  There are four of them, so `Nr = 4`
4. `M(Ng,Nr) += 1`.  Take `Ng = 2`, `Nr = 4` and increment this spot by 1.

If you do this with the other valid locations that have `2`, you'll see that `Nr = 4` each time with the exception of the third row and fourth column, where `Nr = 5`.

---

So how would we implement this in MATLAB?  What you can do is use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to transform each valid neighbourhood into columns.  What I'm also going to do is extract the **centre** of each neighbourhood.  This is actually the **middle** row of the matrix.  We will then figure out how many pixels for each neighbourhood equal the centre, sum them up, and this will determine our `Nr` values.  The `Ng` values will be the **middle** row values themselves.  Once we do this, we can compute a histogram based on these values just like how the algorithm is doing to get our matrix.  In other words, try doing this:

```
% // Your example
A = [1 1 2 3 1; 0 1 1 2 2; 0 0 2 2 1; 3 3 2 2 1; 0 0 2 0 1];
B = im2col(A, [3 3]); %//Convert neighbourhoods to columns - 3 x 3 means d = 1
C = bsxfun(@eq, B, B(5,:)); %//Figure out a logical matrix where each column tells
                            %//you how many elements equals the one in each centre
D = sum(C, 1) - 1; %// Must subtract by 1 to discount centre pixel
Ng = B(5,:).' + 1; % // We must make this into a column vector, and we also must
                   % // offset by 1 as MATLAB starts indexing by 1.
                   %// Column vector is for accumarray input
Nr = D.' + 1; %// Do the same for Nr.  We could have simply left out the + 1 here and
              %// took out the subtraction of -1 for D, but I want to explicitly show
              %// the steps
Q = accumarray([Ng Nr], 1, [4 9]); %// 4 unique intensities, 9 possible locations (0-8)
```

... and here is our matrix:

```
Q =

 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     4     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

If you check this, you'll see this matches with `Q`.

---

## Bonus

If you want to be able to accommodate for the algorithm in general, where you specify `d` and `a`, we can simply follow the guidelines of your text.  For each neighbourhood, you find the difference between the centre pixel and all of the other pixels.  You count how many pixels are `<= a` for any positive integer `d`.  Note that this will create a `2*d + 1 x 2*d + 1` neighbourhood we need to examine.  We can also make this into a function.  Without further ado:

```
%// Set A up yourself, then use a and d as inputs
%// Precondition - a and d are both integers. a can be 0 and d is positive!
function [Q] = calculateGrayDepMatrix(A, a, d)
    neigh = 2*d + 1; % //Calculate rows/columns of neighbourhood
    numTotalNeigh = neigh*neigh; % //Calculate total number of pixels in neighbourhood
    middleRow = ceil(numTotalNeigh / 2); %// Figure out which index the middle row is
    B = im2col(A, [neigh neigh]);  %// Make into columns
    Cdiff = abs(bsxfun(@minus, B, B(middleRow,:))); %// For each neighbourhood, subtract with its centre
    C = Cdiff <= a; %// For each neighbourhood, figure out which differences are <= a
    D = sum(C, 1) - 1; % //For each neighbourhood, add them up
    Ng = B(middleRow,:).' + 1; % // Determine Ng and Nr, and find Q
    Nr = D.' + 1; 
    Q = accumarray([Ng Nr], 1, [max(Ng) numTotalNeigh]); 
end
```

We can recreate the scenario we showed above with the example matrix by:

```
A = [1 1 2 3 1; 0 1 1 2 2; 0 0 2 2 1; 3 3 2 2 1; 0 0 2 0 1];
Q = calculateGrayDepMatrix(A, 0, 1);
```

`Q` is thus:

```
Q =

 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     4     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Gonna try that in few minutes. In meant time I found another [example](http://i.imgur.com/59Al8IE.png). Yet again with no description whatsoever. Hope your solution will work with it too. Thanks for your effort. Much appreciated .

Comment: @sowizz - It won't.  I have to modify my code so that it will work for that example.  That'll be slightly harder though, so I'll have to tackle it later.

Comment: @sowizz - Simply apply the same algorithm.  Instead of checking to see if a pixel in a neighbourhood matches the centre, you find the absolute difference between every pixel in the neighbourhood and the centre.  If the distance between a pixel in the neighbourhood and the centre is `<= a`, then that counts as part of the sum.  Also `d` controls how many pixels are in your neighbourhood.  `d=1` means a `3 x 3` neighbourhood.  The `sqrt(2)` is puzzling me though.  The specifications say `d` is a positive integer, yet the example gives it as `sqrt(2)`.

Comment: I think those are two different approaches. Let's stay with *d* being positive integer as it is written in the paper and the second example comes from some lecture slides.

Comment: @sowizz - Done.  I've modified my code.  Good luck!  Was my explanation good enough for how to compute `Q`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, since it is as detailed as it gets. I will implement features from OP tomorrow and see if they have any discriminative power in my application. Certainly hope so. Will be back with results. Thanks once again.