# Texture detection in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, classification, matlab-cvst

I want to detect if there is a texture in captured image or not. Texture can be seen in attached the image (in black and white). Although there is also a micro-texture but ignoring this I want to detect the the b/w textured region, if this exits or not.

[image]

I tried to matlab traincascadeObjectDetector tool but the result I obtained is not not good (shown by skyblue rectangle).

original image: [image]

desired result: [image]

Can someone suggest me some alternate way to do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try using texture descriptors.  One thing I can think of is a cooccurrence matrix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_matrix.  Also consider looking at the neighboring gray-level dependence matrix.  I wrote a post that talks about how to compute it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019840/neighboring-gray-level-dependence-matrix-ngldm-in-matlab/25023396#25023396

Comment: How constrained is your problem? Do you mean you want to detect exactly this kind of texture? Or any dominant texture in general images? Do you have one image or many?

Comment: Thanks for comment. @MrE I mean the similar texture or like you said dominant texture.Yes, I do have many images.

Comment: @rayryeng, thanks for your suggestion. I'll go through the suggested links.

Comment: @user3563929 can you post the original image without the rectangle? can you also post an image with the desired result (manually marked)? this can help illustrate what you want to achieve here.

Comment: @Shai, Thanks for your consideration, I have updated the post. Similar to the face detection i want to detect this texture, whether this exists or not, in the image.

Comment: @user3563929 do you have training images with similar texture marked?

Comment: @Shai, Yes I have similar images. Do you mean I should follow ann with multiple texture parameters (such as entropy, skewness in pixels value distribution of the texture) as inputs ?

Comment: @user3563929 I think in your case you can do simple [NBNN](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~irani/PAPERS/InDefenceOfNN_CVPR08.pdf) classification of the image patches themselfs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the texture you want to find has strong horizontal edges, you could do the following

1. Find horizontal edges by filtering
2. Threshold by some value
3. Use morphological operations to clean noise

Any more complex texture will require texture descriptors (as @rayryeng has suggested correctly).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the problem is how can i confirm the denoised image has the texture? I want to detect whether this exists or not.

Comment: @user3563929, if the last image has more than N white pixels, consider that it exists