# How to detect texture or non-texture in image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, textures, image-segmentation

I known that the question can be not satisfy for forum,but I think I can find the help from many smart image processing guys. My question is that, I have a image include texture and non-texture in image. How to detect the region that is texture region? Could you suggest to me any algorithm or parameter to distinguish non-texture region and texture region?
Thank you so much
[image]
**UPDATE:**
Based on the suggestion about Gray Level Matrix. I use a tool to extract that texture feature. However, I don't know which is best for my case. Let see the my result and explain help me which feature will be chosen
[image]
@rayryeng: Could you said to me what is purpose of Neighboring gray-level dependence matrix (NGLDM). How to use it in my case?

Comment: All the pixels have a certain intensity value (your image seems to be black and white). To detect texture, you can look at the difference in color intensity of a pixel and its surrounding pixel, also known as the gradient. You could use a filtering matrix and apply to all pixels in the image. You could look at the sobel operator for example: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: Try looking at cooccurrence matrices.  If there is a lack of texture, then the entries will be skewed, but if there is lots of texture, then the entries will be spread.  Take a look at my post on GLDM to help with this task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019840/neighboring-gray-level-dependence-matrix-ngldm-in-matlab/25023396#25023396

Comment: @rayryeng: Could you see my update question? Let me know the image that can use for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can use texture descriptors such as those used in MPEG-7 :

- Homogeneous Texture Descriptor (HTD)
- Texture Browsing Descriptor (TBD)
- Edge Histogram Descriptor (EHD)

You can find the details in some scientific papers such as [Evaluation and comparison of texture descriptors proposed in MPEG-7](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.8065&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or [Texture Descriptors in MPEG-7](http://ivylab.kaist.ac.kr/htm/publication/paper/16.pdf)

A basic way to compute texture descriptors is to use [Gabor filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter). Some of MPEG-7 descriptors are based on it. 
You can also take a look to the [Grey-Level Co-occurrence Matrix texture measurements](http://www.fp.ucalgary.ca/mhallbey/tutorial.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a valid way, or anybody uses this approach (I could not find any scholar papers) but I have an intuitive approach which I used a couple of times and worked fine for me.

I calculate the number of **valid** SURF features in an image and sort images with respect to the number of features. As the number of features increase, texture level also increases in my intuition. Below is my Matlab function that extract the number of features:

```
function [num_pts] = im2surf_feature(im)
if nargin>=1 && ischar(im) && exist(im, 'file')
    im = imread(im);
end
if size(im,3)==3
   im = rgb2gray(im); 
end

ptsI1 = detectSURFFeatures(im);
[~, validPtsI1] = extractFeatures(im, ptsI1);
num_pts = size(validPtsI1,1);

end
```

`detectSURFFeatures` and `extractFeatures` are Matlab functions.

**Note**: I know this is a very late answer, but maybe someone can use it or give me feedback as to why this method is good or bad.